# Using Spider for mysql

Tags: mysql, sharding, database-partitioning

I'm looking for solution to shard my data in mysql w/o changing application code and this project shows up pretty deep in google search result.

While there's not much document available about this, this seems to be a promising out of the box solution to shard ur data across many db.

This is their project description [spider for mysql](https://launchpad.net/spiderformysql)

> The spider storage engine enables tables of different MySQL instances to be treated like a table of a same instance. Because xa transaction and partitioning is supported, it can do decentralized arrangement to two or more servers of data of same table.
>
> The new storage engine "Spider" does work for its strong scalability to access other storage engine of MySQL, to idea to the most considerations are below;
>
> 1:Scalability
>
> 2:Faster Access
>
> 3:Data Synchronizations
>
> 4:Reduce The Cost

It's still quite an active project (it supports mysql 5.5.14 currently) but I don't see many results on the search engine. can you guys tell me why.

Since I don't have much knowledge in this field to assess this, I want to ask about advantages and disadvantages when use this kind of approach. Is the Spider storage the SPOF?

Can I have multiple Spider storage, will it affect transaction committing if I do so?

I need to consider this approach before making a decision to switch to MongoDB.
My application is a write intensive app (a social network project).
And it really needs perfect horizontal scaling in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I m really curious about spiderdb...

I understand that your spider server is just a kind of 'sql router'. You have to define some sharding rules with partition comments and the server will forward and aggregate data from different shards.

Logically it seems to be a SPOF... But you could clone your spider server as many time you want to end with SPOF since SPIDER doesn't store any data. You just have to keep synchro all your spider instances...

Maybe you could do that with a replication scheme to keep spider conf synch...

As I already said, I never used this promising engine, but I m very curious and I hope you'll make a feedback return if you decide to use it

Regards

Comment: I switched to MongoDB for easy sharding :)

Comment: I don't do benchmark myself (but I've gone through some impressive benchmark). I see it as a infinity horizontal scalable database for general usage and that's all I need